# DataTrigger for IsActive doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I was trying to use a `DataTrigger` on the `IsActive` property but it doesn't work.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="Active" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="Not active" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I ended using this sample code that I found over MSDN forums(that as reportedly working) for testing and it doesn't work. Is this a bug or something like an API change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Title="MainWindow"` attribute as it overrides values set by style and trigger.

Related MSDN article: [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)